# Fixing Adobe Acrobat to Microsoft Word Line Munging

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF document that I am converting to Word using Adobe Acrobat (a recent version).  The text converts perfectly fine, but the lines get screwed up.

#### An excerpt from the original PDF looks like this:

[image]

#### And the same excerpt in the Word document looks like this:

[image]

I am more than happy to delete the broken lines and put in new lines myself.  The problem is, I can't seem to select the broken lines.  When I click and drag over the lines to select them, the selection area jumps all over the place, above and below the broken lines, grabbing stuff that is not part of the broken lines.

There are many pages of this, and I'd like not to have to retype them from scratch.  What is causing this, and is there a way to fix it?